# Sending a hl7 test message and listen to it with node

Tags: express, hl7

I want to create a hl7 test message and send it to my express server (which is listening to localhost:3000).

1) I took the message from
http://hl7inspector.com/ and downloaded the inspector.

2) I copied the message into a file (with sublime) and loaded the message into the tool. Here can be a lot of options selected. **What do I need to setup if I want to use it with express?**

[image]

3) I validated the message with the tool, here it throws a lot of warnings (unknown segments and fields). **Is there anything wrong with the message in the link above?** I tried several messages but none of them worked.

[image]

4) I setup a route in express and use the nodengine-hl7 (http://evanlucas.com/nodengine-hl7/) to parse it

```
  hl7 = require('nodengine-hl7')
  hl7Parser = hl7.Parser

  app.get('/hl7/:hl7Msg', (req, res) ->
    console.log req.params
  )
```

**Is the hl7 message sent as a get request, or is it an own request type?? And how can I address the url, in the inspector? I can just select the host and the port.**

EDIT:
I guess hl7 can not be sent and received with express. A new server has to be created. `nodengine-hl7` is a parser only, so I decided to switch to `node-hl7`. The new code is:

```
hl7 = require('node-hl7')
hl7Server = new hl7.Server()

hl7Server.on('hl7', (msg)->
  console.log msg
)
```

### My own research:

How a hl7 message is read
http://www.interfaceware.com/blog/what-does-an-hl7-message-look-like/

A message consists of multiple segments. Each segments has fields (&maybe sub fields etc.). To see when segments and fields start delimiters are used.

`|` Field delimiter

`^` Sub-field delimeter

`~` Repeating field delimiter

`&` Escape character

`\` Sub-sub-field delimiter

The delimiters are always in the message's MSH Segment. The 9th field of the MSH is the message type.

There are certain predefined standarized segments. And with the message type I know which fields are expected.

### Node Packages

- https://github.com/amida-tech/hl7
- https://github.com/ekryski/node-hl7
- https://github.com/evanlucas/nodengine-hl7 (parsing only, no server)

### Testing Tools

[Testing HL7 Messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308945/testing-hl7-messages)

### Additional Ressource:

http://www.hl7.org/

Comment: For sending arbitrary test message somewhere you can use Mike Litherland’s `hl7 comm` - http://nule.org/wp/?page_id=63

Comment: Is there an advantage to the hl7inspector? Is it in general possible to specify a host url and route it. I have the suspicion, that I need to listen with net and create an own port for the hl7 messages.

Comment: Comparing screenshots of the tools it seems to me that `hl7 comm` can send messages while `hl7inspector` can display message (may be even `mllp` receive)

Comment: Maybe a better tool is [HAPI TestPanel](http://hl7api.sourceforge.net/hapi-testpanel/index.html), which has both message inspection/validation functionality and sending/receiving functionality. Also it is fairly easy to use IMHO. I use it exclusively for my own HL7 debugging work.

Comment: See also Inner Harbour Software's HL7Spy - http://ihs.48thave.com/hl7-spy

Answer (score 1):

I tried two tools so far. They can both send messages.

HL7 Soup (windows) and HL7 Inspector (mac). I copied the messages from HL7 Soup to HL7 Inspector to have the same sample. The warnings seem to be unimportant.

**What do I need to setup if I want to use it with express?** &&
**Is the hl7 message sent as a get request, or is it an own request type?? And how can I address the url, in the inspector? I can just select the host and the port.**

I guess it is not possible to use express for that kind of communication. Instead I setup a TCP server with a different port than my express server, later I will use socket.io to communicate between them:

```
net = require('net')
hl7 = require('nodengine-hl7')
split = require('split')
joinStream = require('join-stream')
Parser = hl7.Parser
parser = new Parser()

parser.on('error', (err) ->
  console.log('Error parsing:', err)
)

# parser.on('messages', (messages) ->
#   console.log(messages)
#   console.log "l",messages.length
#   for message, index in messages
#     console.log("Message #{index}:", message)
# )

parser.on('message', (message) ->
  for segment in message.segments
    console.log('Segment:', segment.parsed.SegmentType)
    console.log(segment.parsed)
    console.log('------------------------------------')
  console.log('=====================================')
  return
)

createServer = () ->
  server = net.createServer({
    allowHalfOpen: false,
    pauseOnConnect: false
  },
  (stream) ->
    console.log 'Client connected'

    stream.setEncoding 'utf8'

    stream.addListener 'error', (err) ->
      console.log 'Stream Error' + err
      return

    stream.addListener 'end', ->
      console.log 'Client disconnected'
      stream.end()
      return

    stream.addListener 'finish', ()->
      console.log('done')
    #stream.pipe(split(/\r/)).pipe(joinStream(/\n/)).pipe(parser) #Mac
    #stream.pipe(split(/\n/)).pipe(joinStream(/\r/)).pipe(parser) # Unix
    stream.pipe(split(/\r\n/)).pipe(parser) # Win
    #stream.pipe(split(/\r\n/)).pipe(split(/\n/)).pipe(split(/\r/)).pipe(parser)

    return
  )
  server.listen 59895

  server.on('error', (err) ->
    if (err.code == 'EADDRINUSE')
      console.log('Address in use, retrying...')
      setTimeout(
        () ->
          server.close()
          createServer()
        1000
      )
  )

  server.on('close', (err) ->
    console.log "server closed"
  )

createServer()
```

The solution above is far from perfect. It does not reconnect on disconnecting. I don't properly identify & react on the eol-character which are diff. on win and mac (or maybe per application).

Comment: Your receiver does not seem to implement the `MLLP` protocol. `HL7` version `2.x` messages are **not delimited** by platform-specific new line characters. It is binary (almost human readable) protocol